# Get data from Json by using javascript (jsonplaceholder)

Tags: javascript, json

I've been trying to print the Json file's data on a HTML page. I need to import these data:

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1

I was trying to use this code to get the data from the file:

https://github.com/typicode/jsonplaceholder#how-to

This is what I wrote in my function:

JS:

```
function req1() {
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
        // we print the title and the body of the post recived
    var title = response.data.title;
    var body = response.data.body
    document.getElementById("printTitle").innerHTML = title
    document.getElementById("printBody").innerHTML = body
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="news-btn-div" data-tab="news-2" onclick="req1()">2</div>

    <div id="news-2" class="news-content-container-flex">
      <div class="news-title">
        <span id="printTitle">
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="news-content-1">
        <span id="printBody">
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

So I should get the data once I click on .news-btn-div DIV but I don't get where I'm making the mistake.

## printTitle and #printBody DIVS should be populated with data.

Any advice?

Here my Jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/matteous1/ywh0spga/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had some errors in your second callback of the fetch. You need to get the data from `json` object (name you gave to the `response.json()` callback). Then access to proper elements of `json` in order to print them.
As @Clint pointed out, you closed the callback before using the data received (`title`, `body`), you were trying to access to it outside of its scope.

```js
function req1() {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      const title = json.title;
      const body = json.body;
      document.getElementById("printTitle").innerHTML = title;
      document.getElementById("printBody").innerHTML = body;
    });
}

req1();
```

```html
<div class="news-btn-div" data-tab="news-2" onclick="req1()">2</div>

    <div id="news-2" class="news-content-container-flex">
      <div class="news-title">
        TITLE
        <span id="printTitle">
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="news-content-1">
        BODY
        <span id="printBody">
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: To add to this answer, fetch is async so any code dealing with the data must be in the callbacks. Anything outside will fire before the request has completed.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for the answer, I'm also trying to create more than one button and show the second post when I click the second, the third post when I click the third. In order to do that I duplicated the function but I don't understand how I can use the first as a default. I'd like to open the post number 1 every time I load the page and then when I click on the other buttons I get the other posts. At the moment I'm getting random posts when I load the page. I'm editing my question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Matteo, you should better open a new question with the new doubts you have to avoid confussion with the old one.